# How to delete a contact from a phonebook program

Tags: c++

I made a phonebook program which includes Add and search a contact.

But when I made the delete function, it deleted all the contacts instead of the one I entered.

I know it's a little bit complicated but any ideas?

This is the input in phonebook.txt from which I want to delete a contact:

```
Barney Hackett      0114543053
Luis Avery      01056633489
Hudson Ramsay       01576633982
```

Ihe code is:

```
void DeletePhoneNumber() {
    FILE* search, * fp1;
    //to receive the enter from system("cls")
    char temp;
    scanf("%c", &temp);
    search = fopen("PHONEBOOK.txt", "r+");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    system("cls");
    printf("\t*****DELETE CONTACT*****");
    printf("\n\t Enter Name: ");
    int length;
    length = strlen(SearchName);
    int i, y = 0;
    //string comparison//
    while (fgets(name, 50, search) != NULL) {
                fputs(name, fp1);
            }
            fclose(search);
            fclose(fp1);
            search = fopen("PHONEBOOK.txt", "w");
            fp1 = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
            while (fgets(name, 50, search) != NULL) {


                fputs(name, search);
            }
            fclose(search);
            fclose(fp1);
            remove("temp.txt");
            printf("\n\tPRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
            getch();
            MainMenu();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `PHONEBOOK.txt` the file from which you want to delete an entry? Please show a minimal example of this file.  [Edit] your question and put all relevant clarifications _there_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes the is the file, I edited as you required

Answer (score 1):

I'll use this "answer" space to give you a partial analysis of your code. You can use it to improve your code.

Basically, your loop is all wrong:

```
search = fopen("PHONEBOOK.txt", "r+");
while (fgets(name, 50, search) != NULL) {
    // ...
    while (token != NULL) {
        // ...
        fclose(search);
        search = fopen("PHONEBOOK.txt", "w");
```

You opened the file in append mode, read from it and now close the file, to open it in a different mode. What will it read on the next `fgets` in the while loop?

Opening the file in mode `"w"` for writing will destroy the file. So here is why there are no more entries in your file.

```
        fclose(search);
        MainMenu();
```

At the bottom of the loop you close the file. How can it still read something with `fgets` in the while loop.

Next you call `MainMenu`. But I assume this function calls this `DeletePhoneNumber` function, so you are in a strange loop/recursion. Of course, when you are done with deleting the phone number, you simply return to the main menu, not call it again.